# Getting the user name with SignalR with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: .net, signalr, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I have been working on a .NET backend mobile service. For authentication I use Azure Active Directory. And for the front end a Windows RT application. With the recent introduction of SignalR to .net mobile services I thought I'd give it a look. I quickly ran into the issue many others before me have had of associating a SignalR `ConnectionId` with the authenticated user.

Every resource I've found online says to use `Context.User.Identity.Name`. I've added the Authorize attribute to my hub to only allow authenticated connections. The issue I'm running into is that even though my user is logged in to Azure Active Directory, `Context.User.Identity.Name` is always null.

`Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true`, and `Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType` is `Federated`.

Is there something I am not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first question, but in general you can customize the way `Clients.User()` returns the connections for a given user by implementing `IUserIdProvider` by yourself and injecting your implementation into SignalR. This way you could inspect your requests and extract more info from it. If you find out what's the piece you need in the request (maybe some header, or whatever) you can use it from there to have the related connections associated to it.

Check [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile Service infrastructure set Context.User to be a ServiceUser which contains information about the user. For example, Context.User.Id provides the user id and Context.User.ProviderIdentities provides information from the various login providers including the access token.

Hope this helps,

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

sample problem here. Nothing to do with SignalR in my application but I use Azure AD. And when connecting with Hotmail account I get the Context.User.Identity.Name as null. Not when a user in the same domain as azure ad.

on both occasions this is the same:
Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true, and Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType is Federated.